# How to use Graph Cuts for segmenting objects in grayscale 2D images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I need to extract out some unwanted objects from chest x-ray images using Shai Bagon's [Matlab Wrapper for Graph Cuts](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html) suggested by @rayryeng in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760528/matlab-minimize-the-impact-of-unwanted-objects-in-image-analysis).

I've read the paper by [Boykov](http://csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Papers/ijcv06.pdf) and got some idea of how Graph Cuts work. I've also downloaded the Shai Bagon's Matlab Warpper for Graph Cuts and compiled the required mex files. To get started, I downloaded the simple [example](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html) of image segmentation. But, I'm confused of how I could use

```
[gch ...] = GraphCut(mode, ...);
```

for segmenting the unwanted objects in grayscale 2D images.

Any help is appreciated as always. Thanks.

Comment: @margol - Curiosity.  Did you try running the example script as is?  Pad the image so that it's RGB by doing `im = cat(3, im, im, im);` after you read in the image, then try it and see if it works.

Comment: @margol - are you working on ly on this specific image, or do you have many images with this unknown device that you want to process automatically?

Comment: @margol BTW feel free to contact me if you have any other issues with my wrapper ;)

Comment: @margol my solution is based on a specific threshold (110). clearly this does not apply to the second example you uploaded. You can try a more sophisticated approach: Seeing that the anomaly is only on one of the lungs, you can use symmetry to identify it. Consider all 3x3 patches, what will happen if you try to find all patches from the left lung in the right lung and all the patches from the right lung in the left lung? I suspect you'll find good matches for most of the lung patches but poor matches for the anomaly. Use these matches to compute the data cost (`Dc`) term for the graph cut

Comment: @Shai - Yes. I just observed that for the second example 80 works. So, your answer cannot be an accepted answer for my question. But, it can be a good start. I do agree that the anomaly works. Could you please explain more on how I could use the matches to compute the DC?

Comment: @margol can you extract all (say) 3x3 image patches of the right lung and left lung?

Comment: @margol flip the lungs and extract all flipped patches as well. Then find the distance of each patch to the nearest flipped patch from the other lung. I expect lung patches to find close matches in the flipped lung, due to symmetry, while anomaly patches to have poor matches and hence large distance. These distances can be used as data term for the graphcut.

Answer (score 4):

The very basics:

```
img = imread('http:%//i.stack.imgur.com/nntda.png'); %// read the image
img = img(:,:,1); %// use only one channel as it is a gray scale image
```

Observing that the object is mostly brighter than 110, while the rest of the lungs are darker than this value, you can define the per-pixel data term:

```
Dc(:,:,1) = img > 110; %// cost of 1-st label (bg): penalize pixels brighter than 110
Dc(:,:,2) = img < 110; %// cost of 2-nd label (fg): penalize pixels darker than 110    
lambda = 11; %// relative weight of smoothness cost vs. data cost
Sc = [0 1; 1 0]; %// give 0 cost for bg-bg or fg-fg transitions, and 1 cost for fg-bg transitions
```

Perform the optimization using `GraphCut` wrapper:

```
gch = GraphCut( 'open', Dc, lambda * Sc ); %// define the graph
[gch L] = GraphCut('expand', gch ); %//optimize and get the labeling L
gch=GraphCut('close',gch); %// clean up the mess
```

---

#### What can you do next? <sub>(Apart from upvoting and accepting this extraordinary answer)</sub>

1. Use a more sophisticated data cost - use L1 or L2 "distance" from the 110-level threshold.
2. Use a "smoother" smoothness cost - make the smoothness cost dependent on image edges.
3. Use an 8-connected grid graph rather than the default 4-connected - this will reduce the "staircase"-ness shape of the segmentation boundary.
4. Use a better foreground/background model - make an appearance model based on image patches rather on single pixels.

I'll leave it to you to figure out more exciting ways to improve on this method...

Comment: @margol - I'm not finished yet!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Could you please tell me how to implement the first two suggestions? or at least the first one? Graph Cuts are a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @margol to implement (2) read the documentation of `GraphCut` on constructing a graph with `vC` and `hC` (vertical and horizontal costs) I believe I use these terms in the example on my webpage.

Comment: Nicely done Shai!  This is a great example on how to set up Graph Cuts for use!  Obviously you would know as it's your wrapper!